SIM(3) conversion to SE(3) after pose graph optimization
To address scale drift in mono slam solutions, the euclidean transformations are converted to SIM(3) transformations and pose graph optimization is run on the 7dof pose graph.
My confusion is, how do you revert back from SIM(3) to SE(3) after the pose graph optimization is complete?
Multiple papers reference keeping the rotation matrix the same and scaling the translation vector using the scaling variable, but I don't understand why this works.

After looking at this I think I got an idea, but I'm not sure why they use $s*t$ to scale the translation vs $\frac{1}{s}*t$.
From my understanding, basically the scale applied to the transform is implicitly incorporated into the optimization process and you must "un-do" it.
ex $t_{impl} = s*t_{actual}$,
Thus to restore the correct scale(as in un-do the scaling) you need to remove the $s$ factor which you can do via division.
In other words we can really view sim(3) as $ T = s(Rx + t)$.
